# Precise positioning of three equal DIVs (33.33% each) under browser cross-compatibility

Tags: css

I have a problem with *precise* positioning of three equal divs.

My humble knowledge of math reminds that `33+33+33=99%`, and `1%` is missed. Moreover, `33.33+33.33+33.33=99.99%`, but browser compatibility does nothing with it.

```
<div id='products-choice-wrap'>
  <div id='products-choice'>
    <div id='choice1' class='three-bubbles'>
      <img src='/products/image1.png' alt='' />
    </div>
    <div id='choice2' class='three-bubbles'>
      <img src='/products/image2.png' alt='' />
    </div>
    <div id='choice3' class='three-bubbles'>
      <img src='/products/image3.png' alt='' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#products-choice-wrap 
    { position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: 0; 
    top: 100px; text-align: center; }
#products-choice      
    { position: absolute; width: auto; left: 40px; 
    right: 40px; margin: 0px auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; height: auto;
    max-width: 1080px; }
#products-choice div  
    { position: absolute; top: 20px; height: auto;
    overflow: auto; width: auto; padding-bottom: 200px; }
#products-choice #choice1.three-bubbles 
    { left: 0; right: 66.7%; }
#products-choice #choice2.three-bubbles 
    { left: 33.37%; right: 33.37%; }
#products-choice #choice3.three-bubbles 
    { left: 66.7%; right: 0; }
```

In this construction three images are situated in the center of the page in a row. In case of small resolution they become smaller while `#products-choice` becomes narrow. The attribute `max-width` prevents images from overzooming.

Positioning should be very precise because of smooth lines connections between them (see links to examples below). The problem appears when comparing different resolutions in different browsers. It looks like in Chrome such positions as `33.37%` to `66.7%` provide excellent picture both on resolution 1280x*** (`#products-choice` is `max-width: 1080px`) and smaller 1024x*** (`#products-choice` width becomes 929px). Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r998h.jpg) for image.

IE and Firefox show a 1-px-gap between images, which disppears and appears again after browser size changing. Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVCEF.jpg) for image.

What can I do to say Chrome, IE and Firefox exact width (which is actually 1/3)?

Comment: You clearly want to use a list (UL element) instead of DIVs.

Comment: Would giving the middle item 34% be a problem?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas you mean `<ul>` element? But how can it help me to set images in a row?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas 34% sure can be done, but all images are the same width and in case of max width it will be a little bit deformed? Also, you see the connections between images which are with smooth lines.

Comment: Whenever you have multiple elements that are of the same class, you use a list. That's the general rule. So instead of DIV > DIV > DIV > IMG, you want DIV > UL > LI > IMG.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas thank you, I understood about `ul` element. But whatever container is, I should use `position: absolute`, and (I suppose) problem will not be ruled out.

Comment: Yes, absolute positioning or floats or display inline-block... you use one of those CSS techniques to have the items appear side by side.

Comment: How precise do you want it to be? What happens for a container with a width that isn't divisible by 3?

Comment: @BoltClock I suppose if CSS can resize image which is, for example, `{ width: auto; left: 0; right: 50% }`, why can't resize with width=1/3?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Seeing as this is choice 1 2 and 3, wouldn't an `<ol>` be more appropriate, if anything? "Whenever you have multiple elements that are of the same class, you use a list." <-- That's completely false, not sure what you mean by it. Correct markup is determined by what the content ***is***, not what HTML attributes it has or what you want it to look like.

Comment: @Madmartigan OL makes more sense in this scenario. But I don't care about the OL/UL difference. My main goal is to avoid divitis. *** My rule is not good? Could you give an example? In what scenario of sibling elements which are of the same class is using a list not appropriate?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: An example would be if they are paragraphs or table cells, or divs used for layout. There are lots of examples. I agree with your intentions, but your rule of thumb is simply not true. Using the wrong tag is worse than not using the "best" one.

Comment: @Madmartigan I see what you mean. Let's restrict my rule only to sequences of DIV elements then.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Still fully disagree, it *might* be an indicator but definitely not a rule. Example with div elements: http://jsfiddle.net/DVRXT/ Should be a list? Definitely not.

Comment: @Madmartigan I guess I used an ambiguous term. I didn't mean CSS class. I meant elements that are structurally and content-wise alike (which we of course can't say for a header and a footer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve perfect 1/3 widths at all times with an elastic layout, so here's what I suggest:

Instead of using the `position` property to place your images, `float:left` them instead. This will ensure the three images are pressed up tight against one another, without the 1px gap appearing between them.

The downside: Sometimes you'll have a 1px gap to the right of the last image. You can sort of cover this up by assigning a background to the wrapper element, but in your case it seems like a better deal than having your images split apart.

```
.three-bubbles {
    float:left;
    width:33.33333%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qemUY/2

I left a lot of your CSS in which wasn't needed, because I don't know all of your requirements, but if you take this approach, your current code can be trimmed down considerably.

Simpler demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qemUY/4

Comment: Thanks @Madmartigan, now there is no gaps, but the zoom thing isn't working now. These images became smaller when resolution decreased, and now they are in a row without any gaps, but don't resize.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but can this be solved by `.three-bubbles img{width:100%}`? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qemUY/6/

Comment: Oh, I thought it wouldn't keep aspect ratio. But it works as I need. Thank you! Actually, the gap to the right doesn't mean much for me - my three images are floating in the middle of page, so it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

`#products-choice-wrap {width: 99.99%;}` or a lower value.

I had this issue before and I fixed it by setting the wrapper with `{width:99.92%}`.

I don't know why "99.92%", but I just tried some values on the inspector and that was the best fit.